# Jquery format for Spring Mvc Form Radiobutton

Tags: jquery, forms, spring-mvc, radio-button

I'm new to using Jquery for Spring MVC.

Here's my jsp code:

```
<form:radiobutton id="radio" class="radioSelect" path="version" value="6"/>6
<form:radiobutton class="radioSelect" path="version" value="7"/>7

Field1<form:input id="6" class="fieldsSpecific" path="field1"/>
Field2<form:input id="7" class="fieldsSpecific" path="field2"/>
```

I wish to show field1 when radiobutton is selected to 6 and hide field2 and vice-versa for 7.

Here's my Jquery:

```
    $(".radioSelect").each(function(){
    showSpecificFields(this);
});

$(".radioSelect").click(function(){
   showSpecificFields(this);
});


function showSpecificFields(obj){
    if($(obj).is(":checked")){
    var radioVal = $(obj).val();
     $(".fieldsSpecific").each(function(){
         if($(this).attr('id') == radioVal){
             $(this).show();
         } else{
             $(this).hide();                 
         }
     });   
    }
}
```

The Jquery doesn't run. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the JavaScript? The Chrome browser has a very nice built-in debug tool, and you can install debug tools for IE (Developer Toolbar) and FireFox (FireBug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm developing this code from Work Place, where we can't use Chrome. So I resorted to using `<input type ="radio">` without form, handling the Form part separately in my ModelAndView.